# Requst data(post) not bind to a POJO in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to map the form data into a pojo, so i i set the POJO as a method parameter. So then request data should bind to the pojo. But it not working. I am using spring `4.2.3.RELEASE`. This is the my code

## PersonDto class

```
public class PersonDto {

private int userId;
private String userName;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

## UserController class

```
@Controller()
@RequestMapping("/u")
public class UserController {

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(PersonDto dto){
    System.out.println("Name : "+dto.getUserName());
    return ""+dto.getUserName();
}

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String userHome(){
    System.out.println("UserDetailsController Index");
    return "user-home";
}
}
```

in here home request mapping is working. But when i send post request to `/add` then PersonDto is empty. This is how i send request[image: request] What is the reason for this?

Comment: @Abdelhak No that is not the problem as i said `home` request is working fine. No need to put nameApp here. `addUser` method print statement also printing as null.

Comment: You have to do, as dlcole advised in the answer. Just mark method's parameter with @RequestBody

Comment: @KenBekov i did it. This is the msg i got. `The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.`. I'm not sending json data. I'm sending form data as a POST request.

Comment: It will be better if you would provide html-code of form instead of form screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the PersonDto dto in your method parameter with @RequestBody to indicate it should be bound to the request body:

```
public String addUser(@RequestBody PersonDto dto){
```

Comment: No `@RequestBody` not needed. When i used it `415` error occure. because i send the form data as a POST request

Answer (score 0):

try this options:

1. Use @RequestBody in POST method.
2. include maven dependency for jackson

   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: Jackson is not needed in this case. Request model binding works without json

Comment: @KenBekov no need of jackson .. u are right. This is simple thing and should work. But not working i can not believe this.

Comment: if you added spring web project, then yes Jackson is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark your method parameter with `@ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("dto") PersonDto dto){
    System.out.println("Name : "+dto.getUserName());
    return ""+dto.getUserName();
}
```

Note, that you can specify name of model attribute. If you use `<spring:form>` tag check you form `modelAttribute` attribute:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/someaction" modelAttribute="dto">
   ...
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be pretty late to the party, but if this issue is not yet resolved (since I don't see any accepted answer), this answer may help. I had a similar issue and realised that I had not added a constructor wherein all the parameters passed in request body could be set. So perhaps adding the following constructor:

```
public PersonDto(int userId, String userName){
     this.userId=userId;
     this.userName=userName;
}
```

Please let me know if this works for you. If something else already did, please share your answer since it was quite a task for me to realise my silly error.